# Convert jQuery to plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I convert this `jQuery code` to `plain JavaScript`?

```
$("#txtTestNumbersOnlyRegex").keyup(function () { 
  var newValue = $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
  $(this).val(newValue);    
});
```

Comment: עניתי לך למטה, שאל אותי מה שתרצה

Comment: Google or check sites like http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free code conversion service

Comment: אני מנסה להשתמש בזה באנגולר 2 אבל לא עובד. איך אני יכול למחוק אותיות שהמשתמש מכניס באנגולר 2? נסיתי לשים את הקוד בקומפוננטה אבל לא עובד

Comment: תראה, אני לא מכיר אנגולר 2..אבל יעזרו לך בפייסבוק, יש קבוצה של מפתחים:
https://www.facebook.com/groups/jsisrael/

Comment: `<input type="number" />` even better :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply as below

```
document.querySelector('#txtTestNumbersOnlyRegex').onkeyup = function() {
    var newValue = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    this.value = newValue;
}
```

**Update: With Angular**

```
// app.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }

// app.component.html
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" (keyup)="replacer(value)">

// app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 4';

  text: string;

  replacer(value: string) {
    this.text = value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  }
}
```

[Here is the example code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vkqkq1?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: how would you use it in angular 2 for <input type="text" id="txtTestNumbersOnlyRegex" />

Comment: thanks man!! but i get the following error: ERROR TypeError: _co.replacer is not a function

Comment: @EladNachum Did you checked the example?

Comment: yes i copied the code but it doesn't work with my code :(

Comment: @EladNachum You should generate angular application first with [Angular CLI](http://cli.angular.io/)

Comment: now i get ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Comment: @EladNachum That `text` parameter cannot be passed to the `replacer(text)` function because your `ngModel` is `data[0].id`. In my example i passed `ngModel` as the parameter of `replacer` function.

Comment: @EladNachum So it should be corrected as `<input type="text" (keyup)="replacer(data[0].id)" id="id" [(ngModel)]="data[0].id" name="id" required>`

Comment: @EladNachum Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

One possible Jquery->JS conversion,

```js
document.getElementById('txtTestNumbersOnlyRegex').addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    var newValue = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    this.value = newValue;
});
```

```html
 <input type="text" id="txtTestNumbersOnlyRegex" />
```

For angular: grab your input element like this

```
var elm = document.getElementById('txtTestNumbersOnlyRegex')
   angular.element(elm );
```

Comment: is it possible to explain the reason for Down Voting ?

Answer (score 0):

## Fairly easy conversion:

Use the DOM [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) command for listening to events on your element:

```
document.querySelector("#txtTestNumbersOnlyRegex").addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    var newValue = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
    this.value = newValue;    
})
```

Comment: `$(this).val()` is jQuery